# Import dependencies for a block of classes

Tags: java, eclipse

Working with Eclipse I often need to refresh imported classes/packages in a class, and I usually apply the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> shortcut, but somethimes I also need to refresh imports in many classes, so I was wandering if there is a similar option in Eclipse to save time instead of edit each class.

Can you help me?

Comment: `Ctrl-shift-o` also works out of the project explorer view. Simply shift- or ctrl-click to select all source files you need to clean up, then press `ctrl-shift-o` or go `right-click -> Source -> Organize imports`

Comment: @blgt Perfectly decent answer, please post as one!

Comment: @Duncan Was just pointing out an omission in the question, I wouldn't say it qualifies as a full answer. Besides, E-Riz already posted it with better formatting and more detail : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Package Explorer, right-click on an entire project, a package, or a selected group of classes and choose **Source** > **Organize Imports**. For even more nice clean-up options, select **Source** > **Clean Up...**

In Project Explorer it doesn't work if you select the Project; you have to select a Source Location (typically a folder or folders under `/src` or `/source`.